# Setting one parameter to a certain value upon entering a different parameter - NgSwitch?

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I have an application in which you can add or edit values to a database.

I want to make it so that when I set one parameter to anything (it is empty by default) the second parameter gets set to a specific value.

Further explanation on what I'm actually trying to do:

HTML code:

```
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Status Code</label></td>
    <input type="text" #StatusCode (ngModel)="StatusCodes" value="{{StatusCodes}}">
</form>                                         

<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Eta</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Eta (ngModel)="Etas" value="{{Etas}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Etd</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Etd (ngModel)="Etds" value="{{Etds}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Ata</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Ata (ngModel)="Atas" value="{{Atas}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Atd</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Atd (ngModel)="Atds" value="{{Atds}}">
</form>
```

The `StatusCodes` has a default value of "announced" and only `Eta` has a specified value (other 3 are empty). Upon entering a value for `Ata` I want to have the `StatusCodes` value to automatically be set to "inport".

I'm guessing ngswitch could be used in this situation but I don't know how.
What would be the syntax for it in this case?

If there's better way to get this behaviour please advise me on how I'd achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `ngSwitch` will help you, as it's basically just an extension of `ngIf` - so for showing and hiding DOM elements. By far the most robust option is to handle it explicitly in TypeScript with an event.

So for example, something like:

```
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Status Code</label></td>
    <input type="text" #StatusCode (ngModel)="StatusCodes" value="{{StatusCodes}}">
</form>                                         

<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Eta</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Eta (ngModel)="Etas" value="{{Etas}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Etd</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Etd (ngModel)="Etds" value="{{Etds}}">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Ata</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Ata (ngModel)="Atas" value="{{Atas}}" (change)="updateStatusCode('ata')">
</form>
<form class=form-group>
    <td><label>Atd</label></td>
    <input type="text" #Atd (ngModel)="Atds" value="{{Atds}}">
</form>
```

And then:

```
updateStatusCode(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'ata':
      /* set status code */
      this.StatusCodes = 'import';
      break;
    case 'atd':
      /* etc */
      break;
    case 'eta':
      /* etc */
      break;
    case 'etd':
      /* etc */
      break;
  }
}
```

It's not super-elegant, but it will be the easiest to change and easiest to test (if you're going to write unit tests).

I haven't executed the code above, so please bear in mind that you may have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Yes that did it! Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a pleasure. :)